# unable use keyboard keys in automation script

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to press return after I have added a postcode. However, the method adds the postcode but does not run the second line.

```
def search_postcode postcode
  postcode_search.set postcode
  postcode_search.send_keys :return
end
```

Does anybody have any suggestions? I am currently using the capybara, selenium-webdriver and rspec gems.

Comment: Is there a stacktrace or does it silently fail?  Can you post the (minimal amount of) HTML to consistently reproduce the issue?

Comment: It's not actually failing. I have added `postcode_search.send_keys :semicolon` and thats to give me the postcode plus ; so I know its running but it wont perform the :return function its just sits there.

Comment: [Please have a look at code on Github](https://github.com/shafiqahmedmalik2010/we_are_friday)

Comment: Since send_keys is apparently working it's probably how you're checking for the :return key, or the event being generated by it.   Is that in JS ? is it just supposed to be submitting a form, etc?  You need to asks questions with enough details for people to be able to answer them.

Comment: I am running the automated test using selenium directly in the browser and able to see the test in real time. It suppose to enter my postcode and then press enter to get a list of local gym to my post code. Its typing the post but not pressing the return key to bring up the list of gyms. Then I  am checking if an element is being displayed and it comeback back false. This is because the results are not being displayed. Apologies in advance if that does not make sense.

Comment: You haven't explained how you're detecting the enter key being pressed to trigger the list

Comment: Just a wild guess, but how about using `:enter`? [Selenium::WebDriver::Keys](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Keys#KEYS-constant)

Comment: @maxple Already tried that aswell with no luck.